# double click to show an div

Tags: javascript

I have used a javascript to show div by onclick but when i click outside div i want to hide the div.

after more searches, i have found an function, and it works perfectly

but there is an issue, the code requires double click for first time, to show the dive

my code:

```
<script>
// click on the div
function toggle( e, id ) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.display = ( el.style.display == 'none' ) ? 'block' : 'none';

  // save it for hiding
  toggle.el = el;

  // stop the event right here
  if ( e.stopPropagation )
    e.stopPropagation();
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  return false;
}

// click outside the div
document.onclick = function() {
  if ( toggle.el ) {
    toggle.el.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

</script>
<style>#tools{display:none;}</style>

<div id="tools">Hidden div</div>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle(event, 'tools');">show/hide</a>
```

This is my full code, you can test it on your computer.

The question is: The function requires two clicks, i want show the div on click ( one click ) Not ( Double Click )

Comment: The question is: The function requires two clicks, i want show the div on click ( one click ) Not ( Double Click )

Comment: Here's an example to test with: http://jsfiddle.net/JjChY/

Comment: @Rocket it's requires double click, Not one !! try to refresh the page

Comment: @AlaaGamal: I didn't fix the problem, I just made an example so others could see the problem.

Comment: @Rocket Ah am sorry, and thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/JjChY/1/

Change

```
el.style.display = ( el.style.display == 'none' ) ? 'block' : 'none';
```

to

```
el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none' || el.style.display == '') ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Comment: Can i use toggle('tools'); instead of toggle(event, 'tools'); ?

Comment: @AlaaGamal: No.  You need to pass the `event` object, so you can `e.stopPropagation`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
el.style.display = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("tools")).getPropertyValue("display") == "none" ? 'block' : 'none';
```

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `el.style.display` only reads from the element's inline styles, not its CSS.

So, on the first click `el.style.display` is `''` (blank string), so it's set to 'none'.  Then the second time, `el.style.display` is `'none'`, so it works.

You need to try to read from the element's CSS if its inline styles are blank.  I'm going to use the `getStyle` method from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) for this:

```
function getStyle(x, styleProp) {
    if (x.currentStyle) {
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    }
    else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    }
    return y;
}

// click on the div

function toggle(e, id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var display = el.style.display || getStyle(el, 'display');
    el.style.display = (display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';

    // save it for hiding
    toggle.el = el;

    // stop the event right here
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    return false;
}

// click outside the div
document.onclick = function() {
    if (toggle.el) {
        toggle.el.style.display = 'none';
    }
}​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/JjChY/2/

Comment: Thanks again for your code, it's works fine, but i need a short code

Comment: @AlaaGamal: Why do you *need* "short code"?  I'd suggest doing things the "correct way" before doing them the "short way".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as to why this needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little convoluted. It can be written much simpler:

```
<script>
var toggle = function(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.className = element.className === 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden';

  return false;
};
</script>

<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<div id="tools" class="hidden">Hidden div</div>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('tools');">show/hide</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for shorten my code, But i want when i click outside div i want to hide the div., can you please edit your code to match my needs?

Comment: @AlaaGamal you should be able to figure that out using your old code and the code i posted. we're not here to do your job for you.

Comment: i am sorry. i don't mean that, i just beginner in javascript and i though i can't mix your code with mine,

Comment: i've made many modifications on my code And finally i have failed!! i think i will continue with my old code Thanks Again for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery, you could do something like this for the click outside.

First, set a class on the "tools" div when the mouse is inside it.  Remove the class when the mouse is not inside it.

```
$('#tools').hover( function() {
    $('#tools').addClass("inside");
},
function() {
    $('#tools').removeClass("inside");
});
```

Then, track clicks on the HTML.  Hide if the "inside" class is not on the "tools" div.

```
$("html").click( function() {
    $("#tools").not(".inside").each( function() {
        $("#tools").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of adding a class, why not just detect if the clicked element was `#tools` or not?  `$('html').click(e){ if(!$(e.target).is('#tools')){`

Comment: Learn something new every day :-)